# How to queryset filter with two lists?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I am very new to django,
I have two list and I want to filter the values from table. I was using this query but this is giving me unions of two list i.e OR. I want something with AND i.e filter values this way `retail_item_list = [100,120]` and `city_id_list = [1,2]` the output should be on the basis of these combination `(100,1)` `(120,2)`

`val = list(KVIItem.objects.filter(Q(retail_item_id__in=retail_item_list, cms_city_id__in=city_id_list)).values("retail_item_id","cms_city_id","active","id").order_by('-id'))`

EDIT 1:
Example

```
retail_item_list = [10005681, 10005681, 10013955, 10013955, 10067631]
city_id_list = [959, 956, 959, 956, 2074]
```

Using this query

```
qfilter = Q(
            *[
                Q(cms_city_id=city,retail_item_id=retail)
                for city,retail in zip(city_id_list,retail_item_list)
            ],
            _connector=Q.OR
        )
        val = list(KVIItem.objects.filter(qfilter).values("retail_item_id","cms_city_id","active","id").order_by('-id'))
```

I am getting the result of these combinations:
`(10005681,956), (10013955,959), (10013955,956), (10067631,2074)`

But the goal is to get these combination result:
`(10005681,959), (10005681,956), (10013955,959), (10013955,956), (10067631,2074)`

This one is missing from my result: `(10005681,959)` [first combination]

EDIT 2: qfilter print

```
"(OR: (AND: ('cms_city_id', 959), ('retail_item_id', 10005681)), (AND: ('cms_city_id', 956), ('retail_item_id', 10005681)), (AND: ('cms_city_id', 959), ('retail_item_id', 10013955)), (AND: ('cms_city_id', 956), ('retail_item_id', 10013955)), (AND: ('cms_city_id', 2074), ('retail_item_id', 10067631)))"
```

EDIT 3: this function will return higher id row.

```
def get_latest_kvi_item_among_same_items(val):
    dct = {}
    for v in val:
        if v['cms_city_id'] not in dct:
            dct[v['cms_city_id']] = v
        else:
            d = dct[v['cms_city_id']]
            if v['id'] > d['id']:
                dct['cms_city_id'] = v
    valus = dct.values()
    a = list(valus)
    return a
```

Comment: The problem is that if I run this locally, it does work. What Django version/database do you use? Can you share the data in the database?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ydwxB3Qr this data it is showing, can you check here on link?

Comment: When I create records with the given data, I get 31 records, and that is the same as the number of Items in your codepile code fragment.

Comment: Yes because records have different id's. 
combinations can have different id. and we have to fetch the latest id.
if `'retail_item_id': 10005681, 'cms_city_id': 956, 'active': True, 'id': 51609` and `'retail_item_id': 10005681, 'cms_city_id': 956, 'active': True, 'id': 51610`
then we will be picking id = 51610 as its id is greater.

Comment: but if they have the same id, then Django will not create a new record, but update the existing one. So if created a record with `(10005681,959)` for `id=1`, and later you do this with `(10005681,956)` and `id=1`, then it will not create a new record, but update an existing one.

Comment: If you want to use a duplicate `id`, then you will need to specify another field as `primary_key=True` to allow "clashes" in the `id` field.

Comment: Your queryfilter code worked. what i did is that i fetched all the result first from database codepile.net/pile/ydwxB3Qr this i got the result. and then I code some logic in here that to give only those combinations which has higher id. 
for example:

'retail_item_id': 10005681, 'cms_city_id': 956, 'active': True, 'id': 51609` 'retail_item_id': 10005681, 'cms_city_id': 956, 'active': True, 'id': 51610`

if these are the two result I'll get then after that I am traversing of each combination and returning those with higher id.

I updated the code in EDIT 3,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `Q` object that will elementwise require that if `retail_item` is `100`, then `city_id` should be `1`; or if `retail_item` is `120` and `city_id` is `2`.

We can do that with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qfilter = Q(
    *[
        Q(retail_item_id=retail, cms_city_id=city)
        for retail, city in zip(retail_item_list, city_id_list)
    ],
    _connector=Q.OR
)

KVIItem.objects.filter(qfilter)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but will this work in this case also? if i have 
`retail_id_list = [100,100,102]` and `city_id_list = [1,2,3]`

i can have duplicate retail_ids meaning this can exist in different cities.

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: yes, in that case it can match `city_id=1` or `city_id=2` if `retail_id=100`.

Comment: is that mean that it will filter like this now, `(100,1)` , `(100,2)` , `(102,3)` this way?

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: yes.

Comment: that will be awesome, I am going to try this, and will let you know in 10 mins.
thank you for helping

Comment: Currently I have `retail_id_list = [10005681, 10005681]`
and `city_id_list = [959, 956]`
and it fetches result for `(10005681,956)` only. 
but the goal is to get `(10005681,959)` , `(10005681,956)` for both

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: normally that will be the case, both will be returned. Are you sure you did not swap the retail/city values.

Comment: getting only single result i.e only for this `(10005681,956)`
but want this `(10005681,959) , (10005681,956)`

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: can you please edit the question with the model, the sample data in the database, and the way you are querying this? and the result of `print(qfilter)` (before filtering with it, so before the last line).

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: did you use *other* filters (before/after the filter with `qfilter`)? or a `.distinct()`, ... Normally the list is named `retail_item_id` but you named the list `retail_id_list` in your last example.

Comment: I have edited the question with more context. I'll update it with `print(qfilter)` .
but you can have a look till now.

Comment: When printing this `print(qfilter)` it says `q object is not iterable`

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: you should print it immediately *before* the `KVIItem.objects.filter(qfilter)` line, so *not* in the list comprehension or the construct of `qfilter`.

Comment: `logger.info(str(("[KVI_ACTIVE_STATUS] :qfilter print ",list(qfilter))))`
I was running this on server and to see the logs I had to use the logger and so printing this way, and this way it is saying `q object is not iterable`.

How can i print qfilter in logger form?

Comment: @nihalsrivastava: but you should *not* call `list(...)` on it. Perhaps `str(...)` but that's it, so `logger.info(str(qfilter))` You can not apply `list(...)` on a Q object itself.

Comment: Update code with qfilter print, please check